# Finding percentage of feature in raster using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, query

I am attempting to find the percentage of polygon features at a 5 meter resolution that are located inside each 25km raster cell. I am looking to assign percentages to each cell based on the percentage of a feature appearing in the cell (10%, 20%...).

Is there a tool that can do this procedure?

The raster being limited to only a single value field has prevented me from being able to run attribute queries.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of a few possible solutions in ArcGIS - the methodology is a bit involved, but it should solve your problem.

1) Use [Create Fishnet (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//00170000002q000000) (available at all license levels) to create a 25x25km grid of rectangular cells. This will have to be created concurrent to your raster (match the raster cells to the polygon grid cells) - you can do this using the *origin_coord* parameter.

2) [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) the fishnet with your polygon featureclass based on a common attribute - something such as a simple ID field will work.

3) [Split](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000006000000) the original polygon featureclass by the grid. Calculate the area of each piece of your original polygons.

4) You now have polygon pieces with an ID assigning to the the original whole polygon and the area of each. From this you can calculate the percentage of the whole polygon that each piece represents. This part may be a bit trickier to automate, but can be completed using the [field calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000025000000).

5) [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) the ID and percentage with the grid.

6) [Convert the grid to a raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000030000000) using the new percentage field.

Comment: Converting to vector for this operation is extremely inefficient. The whole thing can be done in one block stats operation.

Comment: @whuber Could you explain the block stats operation to me, please? I've never heard of that operation.

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Block_Statistics/009z000000qp000000/

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the link. I am confused as to how this can analyse the vectorized data also. It seems to only take in the raster which does not contain the necessary values.

Comment: To what "vectorized data" are you referring?  Your question does not mention any.

Comment: @whuber Apologies, I mean the polygon feature class.

Comment: No problem, but some additional information would help. Of importance are (1) whether the polygons have an attribute (such as land cover type) and you wish to compute cell percentages for each attribute and (2) whether for any given value of the attribute the polygons can overlap or must be disjoint.  If you could edit your question to clarify these points you might get some additional good replies.